# Async.forEach iterator data formatting issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am having an issue with the Mongoose fixture [loader](https://github.com/powmedia/mongoose-fixtures) and I am not sure what is wrong.

When I load my data according to docs such as:

```
var data = { User: [{name: 'Alex'}, {name: 'Bob'}] };
```

It does not load. Exploring the code I see that in this [file](https://github.com/powmedia/mongoose-fixtures/blob/master/mongoose_fixtures.js#L119) there is an async.forEach iterator which doesn't seem to get triggered. Creating a simple file to test I still cannot get this to work as it should. Evidently the console should print 'User' but it does not. Can someone shed some light on what the issue might be? Note that while I have phrased my question about the async, ultimately I am trying to get the mongoose loader to work so I need to stay within their code structure.

```
var async = require('async');

var data = { User: [{name: 'Alex'}, {name: 'Bob'}] };

var iterator = function(modelName, next){
  // not working
  console.log(modelName);
  next();
};

async.forEach(data, iterator, function() { });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pow-mongoose-fixtures` module in the NPM repository contains a bug (see [bug report](https://github.com/powmedia/mongoose-fixtures/pull/9)).

Your code contains the same bug:

```
async.forEach(data, ...)
```

`forEach()` operates on arrays, but `data` is an object. In case of the module, [it was fixed](https://github.com/powmedia/mongoose-fixtures/blob/master/mongoose_fixtures.js#L124) by using `Object.keys()` to get an array of keys. You could use it too:

```
async.forEach(Object.keys(data), ...);
```

To get `mongoose-fixtures` working, install the GitHub version:

```
npm install git://github.com/powmedia/mongoose-fixtures.git
```

There's a couple of changed you need to make to your code as well:

```
var fixtures = require('mongoose-fixtures'); // renamed from 'pow-mongoose-fixtures'
var client   = mongoose.connect(...);
...
fixtures.load(data, client); // need to pass the client object
```